# For loop runs an extra time than what is specified?

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf

So what my code does is that it takes in a list of numbers and outputs consecutive rolling average of all the numbers. My scanf function runs an extra time so I just put in a zero. How can I fix this? Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i,n;
    double numbers[100]; double previous[100]; double x[100];
    double mean[100]; double old_average[100]; double new_average[100];
    printf("Total amount of numbers: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &n);
    for (i=1; i<n+1; i++){
        scanf("%lf\n", &numbers[i]);
        }
        old_average[1] = numbers[1] / 1;
    for (i=1; i<n+1; i++){
        new_average[i] = (((old_average[i] * (i)) + numbers[i+1]) / (i+1));
        old_average[i+1]=new_average[i];
        }
    printf("%lf\n", old_average[1]);
    for (i=1; i<n+1; i++){
        printf("%lf\n", new_average[i]);
    }


        //new_average[i] = (((old_average[i] * i-1) + numbers[i]) / i);
        //mean[j] = numbers[i] + mean

    //printf("%f\n", old_average[1]);
    //for (i=2; i<n+2; i++){
      //  printf("%f\n", new_average[i]);
    //}
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what the input and output look like

```
Input:  
Total amount of numbers: 10
10
8
9
15
12
2
3
8
7
11
0(this is the extra loop)
Output: 
10.0
9.0
9.0
10.5
10.8
9.3
8.4
8.4
8.2
8.5
-1.#QNAN0 (this is the extra loop)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Side note: In C, array indexes start at 0.  You are starting with 1.

Comment: `-1.#QNAN0` is not the extra loop. It is just `new_average[10]`. Your code contains another bug: you used uninitialized `old_average[11]` and invoked *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Format&indent your code properly. It is hard to tell where a block starts and where it ends now.

Comment: @e0k I think start using arrays from index 1 is OK if it is easier to understand unless it invokes out-of-bounds access, and in this case it doesn't invoke one.

Comment: I know, but it was necessary for my code to do the math properly. should i still change it so it starts at index 0?

Comment: Array index start at 0.  Adjust your math rather than array indexing.

Comment: Do not make such substantial edits to your question as it invalidate the answer(s).  Revert to the previous

Comment: To make such a substantial different question, create a new post.  Add links between the 2 posts is a good idea  to show the 2nd one is a follow-on.

Comment: Sorry, i had to wait 90 minutes so i got a little impatient. Wont happen again!

Comment: Array in c is zero based.

Comment: Has everyone in this class posted this homework on SO?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this problem, so I'm voting to close appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove extra `\n`, which means "read until end-of-file or next non white-space character", in each format specifier passed to `scanf()`.

Comment: even after removing it, I can scan in the proper amount of numbers but it still outputs 11 things

Comment: @user5983028 That's because you printed 10 numbers via `for` loop and one number via `printf("%lf\n", old_average[1]);` before the loop.