# My program can find the highest moving average of a list of numbers but can't find it when I run it all through a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, moving-average

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i,n, input_cases, x;
    double numbers[100]; double previous[100];
    double mean[100]; double old_average[100]; double new_average[100];

    scanf("%d", &input_cases);
    double *results = malloc(input_cases*sizeof(double));
    //double *first_average = malloc(input_cases*sizeof(double));

    for (x=0; x<input_cases; x++){

        printf("Total amount of numbers: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for (i=0; i<n; i++){
            scanf("%lf", &numbers[i]);
            }
        for (i=0; i<n; i++){
            old_average[0] = numbers[0] / 1;
            new_average[i] = (((old_average[i] * (i+1)) + numbers[i+1]) / (i+2));
            old_average[i+1]=new_average[i];


            if(new_average[0]<new_average[i]){
                new_average[0]=new_average[i];
                results[x]=new_average[0];}
            else{
                results[x]=old_average[0];
            }
        }
}



    for (x=0; x<input_cases; x++){
        printf("%lf\n", results[x]);
    }

    free(results);
    return 0;
}
```

These are my separate inputs:

```
Input 1:
1
Total amount of numbers: 10
10
8
9
15
12
2
3
8
7
11
Output:  
10.8

Input 2:
1
Total amount of numbers: 3
3
2
1
Output:
3.0

Input When I run the loop more than once:
2
Total amount of numbers: 10
10
8
9
15
12
2
3
8
7
11
Total amount of numbers: 3
3
2
1
Output: 
10.8
5.25
```

So the formula is correct. I think my biggest problem is having the original average (which is the first number divided by 1) by itself. How do i compare to see if my very first number is higher than all of the running averages?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you want to do? Please elaborate with your example.

Comment: Say `n==7`, code scans into `numbers[0]...numbers[6]`.  Later the code uses `numbers[i+1]`  including `numbers[7]` which was never initialized.  Who knows what that was?!.  Suggest double checking algorithm.

Comment: "_`old_average[0] = numbers[0] / 1;`_" Why the `/ 1`?

Comment: @CoolGuy, you're right lol i should just get rid of that

Comment: @chux alright, i will double check. although i've tested it out several times with a bunch of different numbers

Comment: What value do you think could be in the `numbers[n]`? What effect could it have on the results? (Hint: code never puts anything in the _uninitialized_ `numbers[n]`, yet code computes based on that array element).

Comment: @chux each number that i input goes into numbers[n]. atleast, thats what im aware of....

Comment: also, i thought i initialized it at double numbers[100];?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) please follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   When calling any of the memory allocation functions (malloc, realloc, calloc) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: if this is not some challenge question, (which I assume it is not because on of the calls to `scanf()` is preceded by a prompt to the user saying what is wanted,  then every call to the user should be preceded by a prompt, including this line: `scanf("%d", &input_cases);`

Comment: the array `numbers[]` is limited/declared as max of 100 entries, but variable `n` is not checked to assure it is in the range 1...100, so the user could enter anything, say 10000 or -10.  Suggest implement a loop that 1)  outputs the upper/lower limits for `n` and checks that the user entered value is within that range

Comment: regarding this line: `new_average[i] = (((old_average[i] * (i+1)) + numbers[i+1]) / (i+2));`  the value contained at: `numbers[i+1]` has not yet been input, so the value will be trash.  And when inputting the last number will be accessing beyond the upper bound of the array (especially if `n` = 100)

Comment: This again?  Is this the third or fourth time this week that I've seen that same list of data?

Comment: "each number that i input goes into numbers[n]." --> No, code is putting values in `numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], ... numbers[n-1]`, not `numbers[n]`.  Yet code reads and computes with initialized `numbers[n]`.  What impact is that?

Comment: @Martin James Same data, different question, at least for 2 posts.  OP's [earlier post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35640928/2410359) was solved (OP has yet to mark that as accepted) and this is a new question on subsequent issues.  I hope there is not another.

Comment: @user3629249. it HAS been inputted though up above in the first for loop

Comment: when calling the fuction: `malloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple implementation that includes both 'simple' and 'cumulative' moving average calculation and recognizes there are other methods for calculating a moving average.

It outputs the current moving average for each step (an additional datum)

This code cleanly compiles, performs appropriate error checking, and does the intended functionality

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int n;
    size_t input_cases;
    size_t x;
    double numbers[100];

    // these are actually low pass filters
    double simple_movingAverage;
    double cumulative_movingAverage;


    printf( "Enter number of test cases: ");
    if( 1 != scanf("%lu", &input_cases) )
    { // scanf failed
        perror("scanf for number of cases failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    for (x=0; x<input_cases; x++)
    {
        printf("Total amount of numbers: ");
        if( 1 != scanf("%d", &n) )
        { // scanf failed
            perror( "scanf for count of numbers failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if( 1 != scanf("%lf", &numbers[i]) )
            { // scanf failed
                perror( "scanf for number failed" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, scanf successful
        }


        simple_movingAverage = 0.0;
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            simple_movingAverage+= numbers[i];

            printf( "simple moving average[%d]: %lf\n",
                    i+1,
                    simple_movingAverage/(double)(i+1));
        }
        printf( "\n" );


        i = 0;
        cumulative_movingAverage = 0.0;
        do
        {
            cumulative_movingAverage = cumulative_movingAverage * (double)(i);
            cumulative_movingAverage +=  numbers[i];
            cumulative_movingAverage /= (double)(i+1);

            i++;
            printf( "cumulative_movingAverage[%d]: %lf\n",
                i,
                cumulative_movingAverage );
        } while( i < n );
        printf( "\n");

        printf( "%s\n", "weighted_movingAverage not calculated");
        printf( "\n");

        printf( "%s\n", "exponential movingAverage not calculated");
        printf( "\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

here is the output from a typical execution:

```
Enter number of test cases: 1
Total amount of numbers: 5
3 2 1 5 4
simple moving average[0]: 3.000000
simple moving average[1]: 2.500000
simple moving average[2]: 2.000000
simple moving average[3]: 2.750000
simple moving average[4]: 3.000000

cumulative_movingAverage[1]: 3.000000
cumulative_movingAverage[2]: 2.500000
cumulative_movingAverage[3]: 2.000000
cumulative_movingAverage[4]: 2.750000
cumulative_movingAverage[5]: 3.000000

weighted_movingAverage not calculated

exponential movingAverage not calculated
```

caveat: it does have the limitation of a max of 100 numbers in a set